# Using the revealing modul pattern with jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I am re-working some tooltip functionality on my site.

Am experimenting with the Revealing module pattern as laid out here:

http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript

As a quick test i tried this:

```
var tooltip = function(){

    var foobar = 'foo and bar';

    function getAlerter(){
        return alert(foobar);
    }

    return{
        alerter: getAlerter
    }

}();

tooltip.alerter();
```

Which alerts 'foo and bar' as expected.

However, i need to pass the element that triggered the tooltip functionality like so:

```
var tooltip = function(elem){

    var trigger = elem;

    function getAlerter(){
        return alert(trigger);
    }

    return{
        alerter: getAlerter
    }

}();

tooltip.alerter('.trigger');
```

But this returns undefined.  Am not sure why :(

Comment: In this and all the answers, there's a little flaw - the functions should be declared as "vars" to maintain privacy, otherwise they are revealed as globals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are using immediately executing function (`()` at the end of your 'module'), and at the moment when your function is declared and executed no value is passed.

You could tell your `getAlerter` function to accept additional parameter:

```
function getAlerter(trigger){
   // your getter code...
}
```

but it questions the whole idea behind your pattern.
If you want to invoke your module with an element assigned, you most likely should end up with something like this:

```
var tooltip = function(elem){
    // your whole module code...
}('.trigger');
```

or, if you want multiple instances, remove the `()` at the end of your 'module', and run it like this:

```
var myTooltip = tooltip('.alerter');
myTooltip.alerter();
```

if you want to keep it as a single instance, you could easily add `init` method:

```
var tooltip = function(elem){

    var trigger;

    function getAlerter(){
        return alert(trigger);
    };

    function init(elem) {
        trigger = elem;
    }
    return{
        alerter: getAlerter,
        init: init
    }
}();
```

and run it like this:

```
tooltip.init('.alerter');
tooltip.alerter();
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.  I think it has brought into question (like you said) why i want to do it this way.  I think this may be overkill for my pruposes but i wanted to try it just for the sake of trying it you know :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are returning the result of the alert not the value of trigger.

Answer (score 1):

This way

```
var tooltip = function(elem){

    function getAlerter(trigger){
        return alert(trigger);
    }

    return{
        alerter: getAlerter
    }

}();

tooltip.alerter('.trigger');
```

Answer (score 1):

I was too hasty! @wildcard has the right idea

```
var tooltip = function (elem) {

    var trigger = elem;

    function getAlerter () {
        alert (trigger);
        return trigger;
    }

    return {
        alerter: getAlerter
    };
};

var q= tooltip ('.trigger');
q.alerter ();
```